# QT project port to QT5.7

Tags: qt, configuration, installation, qt5

I get an QT project that uses cmake not qmake. CMakeList.txt file includes some QT modules.

```
find_package (Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core  Gui Multimedia SerialPort Declarative)
```

I run QT5.7 using `sudo ./qt-unified-xxxx.run` command. It tried to install /opt/ folder, I didn't change this path.

If I write Qml Quick module instead of Declarative, I get c++11 error.

```
/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:61:4: error: #error "Qt requires C++11 support"
 #  error "Qt requires C++11 support"
```

After installation, I arrange project setting to use cmake. But qt run button is not active due to below message.

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative
```

I check QT5 submodules, QT5.7 does not include `Declarative` module.When

I could not find how to install Declarative module or handle this problem.

Comment: Are you porting from Qt 4.x? In Qt 5.x QtQuick module does what Declarative module did in 4.x, and they are not entirely compatible (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html).

Comment: I dont know the project use which qt version. But CMakeList.txt is looking for QT5. I think it use qt5.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see that Declarative was removed only starting from Qt 5.6 (https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6). Replace it with QtQuick and fix all QML/C++ code if there are errors (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html).

Comment: That's a different problem. At least it compiles.